# Retrieve all rows from a Windows Azure table using WPF and WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, cloud

I've set up a local service and a Windows Azure database. I can access the Azure database and retrieve data from all rows but only from one column at at time.

The database has a table called People with each 'record' treated as a Person. One of the columns in the table is 'Name' and I can retrieve all of the names using:

```
public List<string> GetAllPeople()
{
    string query = @"SELECT value Person.Name FROM DataEntities.People AS Person";

    List<string> resultsAsStrings = new List<string>();
    using (var context = new DataEntities())
    {
        ObjectQuery<string> results = context.CreateQuery<string>(query);
        foreach (string result in results)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                resultsAsStrings.Add(result);
            }
        }
    }
    return resultsAsStrings;
}
```

How would I go about changing the query so that I could retrieve a list of ALL of the Person records with ALL columns in the table as opposed to just the name field?

Is there a better way to read data from an Azure table?

Cheers!

Edit:
When I change the query to:
    @"SELECT value Person FROM DataEntities.People AS Person";

It returns null and my WP7 app crashes. (I also adjusted the code so that it accepted Person instead of string. E.G ObjectQuery

Comment: Querying for type "Person" should return all of the 'records' that you want, why is this not what you want? Also remember that the max amount of records you can fetch from Azure TS is 1000 at a time.

Comment: I've tried that and I'm only trying to get 4 records. I have however found another way of doing it. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the call to CreateQuery:

```
From: CreateQuery<string>
To: CreateQuery<Person>
```

This is required because if you select a Person this won't be a string, but a Person.

Now, could you try not using the type (Person) as alias? Try something like this:

```
SELECT VALUE pers FROM DataEntities.People AS pers
```

And why don't you simply use **context.People**?

Comment: I already have. When trying to retrieve just the name I use string and when retrieving a person I replace all instances of 'string' with 'person'. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Ok, using pers doesn't work I'm afraid. context.People exists but what do I do with it? There's no query method. Is there a better way to read data from an Azure table?

Comment: You can simply do something like: `context.People.ToList()` or `context.People.Select(o => new { Name = o.Name, FirstName = o.FirstName, Age = o.Age, Street = o.Street}).ToList()` to get all people.

Comment: .ToList() doesn't exist but .Select does - however the argument is invalid as it doesn't know what o is...

Comment: Add a using statement for System.Linq at the top of your file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I've used that and my WP7 app is crashing with an exception: "The entity or complex type 'AppModel.Person' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." I feel like we're getting somewhere...

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to consume the results of the query on the WP7 side? Almost sounds like a datatype projection problem...

Comment: I gave up in the end guys - I've found another way of doing it which appears to work. Thanks for all the suggestions though.